# How to add a tooltip for a datagrid header, where the header text is generated dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, tooltip

I need to add a tooltip for a column header of a `DataGrid` (Silverlight 4). I will generate the number of columns and column header text dynamically.

```
GridColumnCreation(....)
{
    IEnumerable allHeaderText = /* Linq query */; 
}
```

How to use this collection to set a tooltip?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done by using DataGridTextColumn & DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle. In the headerstyle tag, use the ToolTipService and bind the content to the dynamic values generated. Here's a sample code for this...

```
        <data:DataGrid.Columns>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FName}" >
                <data:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="dataprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                            <ToolTip Content="Tooltip First" />
                                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    </ContentControl>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </data:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </data:DataGridTextColumn>

            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LName}">
                <data:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="dataprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                            <ToolTip Content="Tooltip Second"></ToolTip>
                                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    </ContentControl>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </data:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </data:DataGridTextColumn>

            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="City" Binding="{Binding City}">
                <data:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="dataprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                            <ToolTip Content="Tooltip Third"></ToolTip>
                                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    </ContentControl>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </data:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </data:DataGridTextColumn>
        </data:DataGrid.Columns>

    </data:DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

where Custdetails.. is something like this..

```
class Customer
{
    public string LName { set; get; }
    public string FName { set; get; }
    public string City { set; get; }
}
```

DataBinding...

```
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>
                                    {
                                        new Customer { LName="Alan", FName="Ameen", City="New York" },
                                        new Customer { LName="Forgeard", FName="Steven", City="Mumbai" },
                                        new Customer { LName="Angur", FName="Paul", City="São Paulo" }
                                    };
dgCustDetails.ItemsSource = customers;
```

This would display the header tooltips... To make it dynamic.. Replace the ToolTip Content with Binding & the desired value...

Answer (score 33):

This can be done even more simply than in @Farukh's answer:

```
<data:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
  <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty"
            Value="Your tool tip here" />
  </Style>
</data:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

Or, if you need to do it in code:

```
var style = new Style(typeof(DataGridColumnHeader));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty,
                             "Your tool tip here"));
column.HeaderStyle = style;
```

Comment: That helped me, but it seems to be overwriting the existing style for Column Headers. How can i get the default style for a DataGridColumnHeader and make my style to base on it?

Comment: Actually, i've already have some header definitions in the DataGrid Template, when i apply the style to the header it seems to be ignoring all style propertys defined by the grid.

Comment: Have you tried setting the BasedOn property of the style to your custom style? E.g. `<Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn={StaticResource MyHeaderStyle}">`

Answer (score 18):

In case it might help anyone. It works when using *ToolTip* property.

```
<DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

Answer (score 11):

If you do not want to create a new style for the Header, simply add a TextBlock for your column header and set the tooltip on it.

```
<DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="ColumnA" ToolTip="ColumnA Tooltip"/>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: This saved my time !

Comment: I like that, it is nice and simple solution and learned that you can put whatever you want in the header.

Comment: This is great. And you can even add a little question mark icon or something like that